# Is there some settings in Maven or Bamboo to restrict the tests to run in the same JVM as Bamboo rather than running in a seperate JVM?

Tags: maven, jvm, bamboo

I use Bamboo and Maven for continuous integration and running tests. Where ever scheduled/dependent maven tests run in Bamboo, it creates a new JVM. I have a huge no. of test for each project configured in Bamboo. There are as many as 20 projects, all have tests specific to them. So JVM number also increases, that makes the server less responsive, since multiple JVM increases the memory footprint.

Is there any settings in Maven or Bamboo to restrict the tests to run in the same JVM as Bamboo rather than running in a separate JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this in Maven `surefire-plugin`:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/forking.html

You have the following choices:

- forkMode=never
- forkMode=once
- forkMode=always

Comment: Thanks Tomasz!. This should help me.

Comment: My pleasure. Please accept the answer or don't hesitate if you have further questions.